# FOR LOOP insert statement with concatenation

Tags: oracle, loops, insert

I'm struggling since 1 hour to find out why this won't work and I finally said 'to hell with it, i'm heading to stackoverflow' :)

```
BEGIN
 FOR c IN ( SELECT ID FROM projects where id <4 )
 LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into project_tools(pj_id,tool_id) values(' || c || ',81)' ;
 END LOOP;
END;
```

I tried many variants of this but no luck!
Can you tell me what's wrong with the above block?
Thanks!

Comment: Where is Commit ?

Comment: the referencing is not correct --> c.ID

Comment: @Thomas thank you. I tried c.ID but when I tried I had concatenation problems and I think this why I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: why are you using dynamic SQL at all?

Comment: @Thomas I'm using it to quickly populate some new tables

Comment: simple use:  insert into project_tools(pj_id,tool_id) values( c.ID,81) ;

Comment: I dont think that would improve the insert too much, then use FOR ALL, or parallel or both. How many rows are we talking about?

Comment: @Thomas about 300 hundred rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see, then you should not use loop, you can solve it in one statement -->

```
  insert /*+ append */ into project_tools(pj_id,tool_id)
  select /*+ parallel(8) */ ID, 81 from projects where id < 4;
```

(parallel works only in EE, and the degree can be any high, oracle will handle it)
You can imporve it with to "make the session parallel" before execute the insert:

```
alter session enable parallel dml parallel 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like;

```
 declare sql_text varchar(2000);
    BEGIN
     FOR c IN ( SELECT ID FROM projects where id <4 )
     LOOP
       sql_text := 'insert into project_tools(pj_id,tool_id) values(' || c || ',81)' ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_text;
     END LOOP;
    END;
```